# Allow snap version of Firefox to access hidden folders

Tags: firefox, snap, hidden-files

SageMath uses a folder of the form `$HOME/.sage/temp/$HOSTNAME/<random four digit name>` to hold html files generated by a plotting routine and calls the default browser to display them.  I want to keep Firefox as my default browser, but there is a problem that it now is a snap, which can not access anything in a path that includes a hidden folder. Is there a way to allow Firefox to access hidden folders or at least a path containing a specific hidden folder?

[John Palmieri at AskSage](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/62518/how-to-set-folder-for-temporary-graphics-files/) explained how to change the `.sage` folder to one that isn't hidden, but that leads to another problem with `.desktop` files that involves invoking `gnome-terminal` in a `.desktop` file and the inheritance of environment variables I'll ask about in another question.

Comment: The SNAP version of Firefox has its problems. Remove the SNAP version and install the apt/deb version.